# next.js Head imported from next/head doesn't work properly on share pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I've migrated from create-react-app to create-next-app to my website, but the Head(app/head) component isn't working properly

Assuming I have a blog, and in pages, I have the following structure: pages/blog/index.js, pages/blog/[slug].js.
In [slug].js, I'm using the Head component so it takes the title of the blog post:
`<Head><title>{post.title}</title></Head>`
The problem is that when using react-share on the blog post it doesn't put the right title, even when I do an inspect element on the page, I can see the right Head values, but the Facebook debug (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) tool doesn't recognize the right title.

Any help will be used. thanks, guys

Comment: Maybe the title is not being rendered on the server, and the FB debug tool doesn't run javascript, so it never sees the title?

Comment: yes, that was the problem. i fixed it

Comment: You should post an answer to your own question; it could benefit others in the future.

Answer (score -1):

the answer is that you should bring data via getInitialProps so it can accessible to component and not via useEffect :)